# What's wrong with my answer finding the resistance?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

This is the question and the solution:
[image]

Here's my answer:
[image]

My answer was incorrect, though I believe my analysis was correct. Can anyone point my mistake? I hope it's not with the signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it:

The mistake happened in **Step 3:** it should be:

$$
-(-2) + V_{src} + 2\cdot I = 0 \\
2 -6 + 2\cdot I = 0\\
I = 2\mathrm{A}
$$

Then, **step 4:**

$$
1 - 2 - I_1 = 0 \\
I_1 = -1\,\mathrm{A}
$$

Then, **step 5:**

$$
R = \dfrac{U}{I} = \dfrac{-2}{-1} = 2 \,\Omega
$$